# How do i make calls to the Firestore database after a user is signed in?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to setup Firebase with React. I can make calls to the database (Firestore) without errors, however, anytime I try to make a call to the database after logging in I get two error messages. The errors only occur after a user has signed in. The ruleset for the database is:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Error messages:

1) Firestore (7.15.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unknown]: Fetching auth token failed: getToken aborted due to token change.

2) FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.

[Picture of the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jeRM.jpg)

[Github Repo](https://github.com/Jeff-Enriquez/check-in/tree/redo-firebase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing an issue that was fixed in 7.15.1, so I suggest updating.  According to the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7151_-_june_11_2020):

> Fixed an issue that prevented the client from connecting to the backend immediately after a user signed in. See [GitHub issue #2923](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2923).